# select last of the Element gg in list of ul li from recursive structure with css

Tags: html, css

I want to select with css the last of child `<li>` that text appear gg 
I want only select Last gg `<li>` Please Help

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container ul li + li:nth-last-child(1) li:last-child {
  border: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="ng-scope">
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>a</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      aa
      <ul>
        <li>
          bb
          <ul>
            <li>
              cc
              <ul>
                <li>
                  dd
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      ee
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                          ff
                          <ul>
                            <li>
                              gg
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>

                      </ul>
                    </li>

                  </ul>
                </li>

              </ul>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Effectively you're trying to find the 'deepest' `<li>` element(s), or the `<li>` element(s) that have no children? Unfortunately this can't be done dynamically with CSS, and would require JavaScript (to the best of my knowledge).

Comment: Incidentally, a simple JavaScript solution is here (if you're willing/able to use it): https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/p2zpcgyz/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
ul { margin:0; padding:0;}
.gg{

color:red;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <ul class="ng-scope">
        <li>
            <ul>
    <li>a</li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
            aa
            <ul>
                <li>
                    bb
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            cc
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    dd
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            ee
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>
                                                    ff
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li class="gg">
                                                            gg
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>

                                            </ul>
                                        </li>

                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but i am not able to add any class because list generate dynamically